# JSF 2.0 + SWF 3 integration tutorial / example

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

Where can i find working example / tutorial for simple webapp on JSF 2.0 integrated with SWF 3 (Spring Web Flow) ? Is this possible ?

Comment: swf is generally perceived as "shockwave flash" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webflow offers great working examples in its distro

```
/projects/spring-webflow-samples/
```

- so don't hesitate to download and run them! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did Google not provide enough?

- http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/05/spring-web-flow-2-2-0-m1-released/
- http://www.installationwiki.org/Setup_for_Spring_Web_Flow_2
- http://spring.ervacon.com/
- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2008/jw-11-intro-to-swf2.html
- http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/intro_spring_faces_1.html
- http://www.springsource.org/webflow

I would recommend grabbing a few books, like [Spring Web Flow 2 Web Development](https://www.packtpub.com/develop-powerful-web-applications-with-spring-web-flow-2/book?utm_source=installationwiki&utm_medium=Spring%2BWeb%20Flow%202%20Web%20Development&utm_term=%20source_packt&utm_campaign=apr_2009).  They'll be more complete than many tutorials.